# Rating system and CSS sprites

Tags: php, jquery, css, sprite

I have implemented three star rating system based on popularity count in my website, but now my client wants to change colors of those three stars (default blue) to red, blue and green which shows the (degree of) popularity.

I've implemented this star rating system using CSS sprites, where I included two star images - golden and gray, in one sprite and displaying these using some logic. Works fine for one color, but how to implement three colours for each star?

HTML

```
<div class="star-box">
   <li>
       <span class="stars"><?php echo $position;?></span>
  </li>
</div>
```

PHP

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['ranking']) || $_SESSION['ranking']['points'] <= 1000 ) {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['ranking']['points']) || $_SESSION['ranking']['points'] == '' ) {
        $position = '0px';
        $position = 0.00;
    } else {
        $position = ($_SESSION['ranking']['points'] * 0.14).'px';
        $position = 0.75;
    }

    $str1 = 'class="active" ';
    $str1 .= ' style="background-position:'.$position.' 9px;"';

}

if( $_SESSION['ranking']['points'] > 1000 &&  $_SESSION['ranking']['points'] <= 5000 ) {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['ranking']['points']) || $_SESSION['ranking']['points'] == '' ) {
        $position = '0px';
        $position = 0.00;
    } else {
        $position = ($_SESSION['ranking']['points']*0.035).'px';
        $position = 1.40;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('span.stars').stars();
});

$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        // get the value
        var val = parseFloat($(this).html());

        // make sure that the value is in (0 - 5) range, multiply to get width
        val = Math.round(val * 4) / 4;
        var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val))) * 16;

        // create stars holder
        var $span = $('<span />').width(size);

        // replace the numerical value with stars
        $(this).html($span);
    });
}
```

CSS

```
span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url(../../images/stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

span.stars span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

SPRITE IMAGE :

[image]

Comment: What you're trying to do is put 3 starts in a row, and each star can be one of 3 colours?

Comment: exactly .. you got it ..

Comment: Just to make sure, what you have now is three starts with two colors?

Comment: yes they appears as like it

Comment: i am total new to css and this system is applied by using css logic and technique hence i am helpless ...please help me ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use session variables etc to control your CSS directly by using a php/css file. You could set star color, sprite position, all based on logic.

Link to your css

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />
```

Your css/php document

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $CSSposition = $position;
?>

span.stars span {
    background-position: <?php echo  $CSSposition ?>;
}
```

Here's a link to php/css document tutorial [click here](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)

Comment: great seems really close to what i am looking for implimenting it........  thanks...a .. lot.....

Comment: Glad to help. This is the best way to control CSS based on php output. If this answer helped please mark it as answered, thanks.

Comment: it works beyond that now i can modify this system to any no of stars and colours thanks a lot for new idea .....

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial on knockout they show how to do the star rating system which you can apply to your code http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings